# How to declare new system property in Android?

Tags: android

I want to add a new system property in android code, a property I can set and get by property_set() and property_get() in native code.

How to add a new system property?
For example I want to declare new sys.newprop

Comment: see this link..will help you..
http://rxwen.blogspot.in/2010/01/android-property-system.html

Comment: I guess uu are looking for custom tag attributes

Answer (score 0):

go to init.rc or your proprietary init.xyz.rc

declare new property

```
setprop sys.newprop 0
```

then now you can use it in your code

```
#include <cutils/properties.h>
property_set("sys.newprop","1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a `HashMap<String,Object>`?